# Turtle doesn't seem to change heading when it reaches the specific patch I ordered it to go to

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to make the turtle face another turtle, or in this case a Node, when it reaches a specific patch/node coordinate. However, once it reaches it, the turtle doesn't seem to read the next `face` command. I am fairly new to netlogo so any help is appreciated.

```
ask trucks
  [
    face node2 317 
    fd 1
    if ((pxcor = -133 ) and (pycor = 47)) ;; Coordinate of the node2 317
    [
      face node 333
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing more of your code relating to nodes etc it's hard to tell, but I would guess that the `trucks` are in fact reading the code to face `node 333` and move forward. However, the next time the procedure runs, the `truck` again will `face node2 317` and get stuck moving back and forth.

To demonstrate, check out this modified version of your code.

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 1 [ pd ]
  reset-ticks  
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    print "I'm facing 10 10 and moving forward 1"
    facexy  10 10
    fd 1
    display
    wait 0.15
    if pxcor = 10 and pycor = 10 [
      print "I'm facing 0 10 and moving forward 1"
      facexy 0 10
      fd 1
      display
      wait 0.15
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

If you want your trucks to move sequentially to target nodes, you'll probably want a `trucks-own` variable that stores the current node to which they want to go, and can be updated to the next node once they get there. Check out the "Link-Walking Turtles Example" in the models library for a sort-of related example.

**Edit**

I think this example will help- using this `setup`, where we define three variables:

- `targets-list`- a list of patches to visit
- `next-target`- the current patch to visit
- `counter` - indexes the `targets-list`

**

```
turtles-own [ counter targets-list next-target ]

to setup
  ca
  crt 1 [
    pd
    set targets-list ( list patch 5 5 patch 5 -5 patch -5 -5 )
  ]
  reset-ticks
end
```

Then, you can have the turtles use the `counter` to select their `next-target` based on the current value of their `counter`. When they get to a target, they increase their `counter` by 1 so that the next tick they will index the next entry in the `targets-list` (using `item`). More detail in comments:

```
to go
  ask turtles [
    ; set my next-target to be the list item indexed by
    ; my counter variable
    set next-target item counter targets-list

    ; face the next-target, and move forward 1 if distance is
    ; greater than 1. If it's less than 1, move-to the target
    ; and increment the counter
    face next-target 
    ifelse distance next-target > 1 [
      fd 1 
    ] [
      move-to next-target 
      set counter counter + 1
    ]

    ; if counter variable is greater than the number of items
    ; in targets-list, reset to 0 as you cannot index an item
    ; that does not exist
    if counter > length targets-list - 1 [
      set counter 0
    ]
  ]

  tick
end
```

Hopefully that gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: that is actually what's happening to the turtle i have right now, how do you suppose I go around this issue. I am trying to let my turtle go thru a controlled path and the turtle will have to go thru several turns. I still find netlogo's syntax a bit confusing. Sorry for the trouble^^"

Comment: I've tried to do how Link-Walking turtles did how they changed headings the way they did it. From what i understand, they moved the turtles using the move-to commands which completely moves/teleports the turtle to the nodes they are targeting not making them move by patch the way im trying to do it. But i dont know, i could be wrong in understanding the way they did it. I'm still trying to get a hang of the syntax netlogo uses.

Comment: @random - Ok, I've made some edits to show one example that I think gets what you're after

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a really good example of what im trying to do. I'll look at how you did this for a while but i do get the basic gist of it. Again thanks and sorry for the trouble ^^

Comment: @random - No trouble at all, happy coding!